# Reset a timer based on when you look at an object in Unity

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I've set up ray cast in Unity that detects when I look at an object based on the tag the object. Now, what I'm trying to do is have a timed event that triggers when I look at my tagged object for a set period of time, then, when I look away I want the timer to reset.

However, I'm having some real trouble in getting this to work. Could someone please look voer my code and point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
public float end_time = 10.0f;
public float start_time;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    start_time = Time.deltaTime;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    EyeTarget();
}

void EyeTarget()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit))
    {
     //  Debug.Log("ray hit (tag): " + hit.collider.gameObject.tag + " : ");
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "floor")
        {
            Debug.Log("Just hit the floor");

            start_time = Time.time - end_time;
            if(start_time <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("looked at floor for 10 seconds");
            }
        }

        if( hit.collider.gameObject.tag != "floor")
        {
            ResetTimer();

        }
    }
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fwd, Color.green);
}

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = Time.time;
    Debug.Log("resetting timer");
}
```

Comment: start_time = Time.time - end_time;
When is end_time set to anything?

Comment: public variable. In my case, 15. Sorry, i'll edit that just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this where I use a slightly different approach:

```
    public float end_time = 10.0f;
    public float start_time;
    private float running_time;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        start_time = Time.deltaTime;
        running_time = 0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

        EyeTarget();
    }

    void EyeTarget()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit))
        {
         //  Debug.Log("ray hit (tag): " + hit.collider.gameObject.tag + " : ");
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "floor")
            {
                Debug.Log("Just hit the floor");

                start_time = Time.time - end_time;
                running_time += Time.deltaTime
                //if(start_time <= 0)
                if ( running_time >= end_time )
                {
                    Debug.Log("looked at floor for 10 seconds");
                }
            }

            if( hit.collider.gameObject.tag != "floor")
            {
                ResetTimer();

            }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fwd, Color.green);
    }

    void ResetTimer()
    {
        start_time = Time.time;
        running_time = 0f;
        Debug.Log("resetting timer");
    }
```