# Issue with Ray casting and timers in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a [follow on from my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429597/reset-a-timer-based-on-when-you-look-at-an-object-in-unity) now I'm looking to extend it's functionality but I'm hitting some major road blocks.

My goal is as follows:

I have a camera that is projecting a ray to hit objects with a specific tag. When the ray hits a tag for a set period of time I'm looking for something to happen, just now all I'm looking for is a debug message or something simple. When the ray doesn't hit any object with a tag I'm wanting my timer to not update. If the user looks away from the object and comes back, I'm wanting the timer to start again from 0 and I want similar functionality should the user look another one of the tags i.e the timer starts again.

How ever, my timer isn't working as intended and it just keeps counting no matter what I'm looking. I've spent 3 hours on this and I've gotten tunnel vision where I keep attempting the same lines of code over and over.

Could someone with a fresh pair of eyes take a look at what I've done so far and point out to me what it is I'm missing / doing wrong?

```
public float end_time;
public float start_time;
private float running_time;

public Texture2D progress_bar_empty;
public Texture2D progress_bar_full;
public Material highlight_material;
public float progress = 0;
public bool hited = false;


public List<string> _tags = new List<string>();

private GameObject hit_object;
private Material oldMat;


RaycastHit hit;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    start_time = Time.deltaTime;
    running_time = 0;   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    EyeTarget();
    Check(hited);
}

void EyeTarget()
{
    try
    {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit))
        {
            foreach(string t in _tags)
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == t)
                {
                    HighLight();

                }                   
            }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fwd, Color.red);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = Time.time;
    running_time = 0f;
    //Debug.Log("resetting timer");
}


void HighLight()
{
    if(hit_object == null)
    {
        ResetTime();
        oldMat = hit.transform.renderer.material;
        hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
        hit_object = hit.collider.gameObject;
        hited = true;
    }       
    else if( hit.transform.tag != hit_object.tag)
    {
        //hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
        hit_object = null;
        hit_object.renderer.material = oldMat;
        progress = 0;
        Debug.Log("hi");
        hited = false;
    }
}
// see if ray has hit object
void Check(bool hit)
{

    if(hit)
    {
        start_time = Time.time - end_time;
        running_time += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( running_time >= end_time )
        {

            hited = false;
        }
    }
    else if( hited == false)
        ResetTime();

}

void ResetTime()
{
      start_time = Time.time;
    running_time = 0f;
    Debug.Log("restting timer");
}
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong but the main problem you're having is that nothing calls `Highlight` unless your raycast hits an object with the correct tag.  You also have an error in `Highlight` in the `else if` where you first set `hit_object = null` then you try to set its material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to leave your version alone as much as possible.  This version will stop the timer when the cursor moves off a tagged object and will start again, from 0, when another tagged object is under the `raycast`.

My code is a little verbose but it makes it easier to see what's going on.

```
    public float end_time;
public float start_time;
public float running_time;

public Texture2D progress_bar_empty;
public Texture2D progress_bar_full;
public Material highlight_material;
public float progress = 0;

public bool trackTimer = false;

public List<string> _tags = new List<string>();

public GameObject lastHitObject = null;
private Material oldMat;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    ResetTimer();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    EyeTarget();

    // Update the timer if and only if we are tracking time AND
    // the last ray cast hit something.
    bool updateTimer = (trackTimer && lastHitObject != null);  
    Check(updateTimer);
}

void EyeTarget()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    bool hitTaggedObject = false;

    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit))
    {
        foreach(string t in _tags)
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == t)
            {
                HighLight(hit.collider.gameObject);
                hitTaggedObject = true;
            }                   
        }
    } 

    // ** Make sure to clean up highlighting if nothing new was hit
    if (!hitTaggedObject){
        HighLight(null);
    }
}

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = Time.time;
    running_time = 0f;
}


void HighLight(GameObject nextHitObject)
{
    // Case1: Last ray and new ray both hit objects
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject != null){

        //1a: same objects, do nothing
        if(lastHitObject.tag == nextHitObject.tag)return;   

        {   //1b: different objects, swap highlight texture
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
            lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
            oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
            trackTimer = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Case2: Last ray hit nothing, new ray hit object.
    if(lastHitObject == null && nextHitObject != null){
        ResetTimer();
        lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
        oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
        trackTimer = true;
        return;
    }

    // Case3: Last ray hit something, new ray hit nothing
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject == null){
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
        lastHitObject = null;
        trackTimer = false;
        return;
    }
}
// see if ray has hit object
void Check(bool updateTimer)
{
    if(updateTimer)
    {
        start_time = Time.time - end_time;
        running_time += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( running_time >= end_time )
        {
            trackTimer = false;
        }
    }   
}
```

`trackTimer` is a state flag, separate from the state of your selected object, that tracks when `running_time` reached `end_time`.  Once those 2 are equal, `trackTimer` flips to false and you need to highlight a new object or rehighlight the current object before the timer will start again.